# Data conversion for string based data for machine learning or deep learning

Tags: string, machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

I have string data in my dataset of the type :

```
AGF.SL.CA.LOSANG.15764
ABC.EMP.GOO.__._ME$.ZR_ME$ATR$GENERAL
SEM.JP.YOO.����_������_�����.ZC_NA:US::SANDO$GENERAL
```

Every record has a category associated with it, and given one such string, I have to use a Machine Learning or Deep Learning approach to identify the corresponding category.

I am confused as to what approach to follow in order to do this. My primary question is, should I keep the strings as is and use string similarity functions, or should I break up the strings into different words, and then do count vectorization on it, and then proceed from there?

Given this kind of data, with just one string to predict the class, what would be the best approach? I have to put this into production so I need look at something which will scale well. I am new to ML so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is this a "AGF.SL.CA.LOSANG.15764" a one record?And is this record follows any sequential pattern?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you can tackle this problem using lstm. Long short-term memory (LSTM) units (or blocks) are a building unit for layers of a recurrent neural network (RNN)

These LSTM will help us to capture sequential information and generally used in case where we want to learn the sequential patterns in the data

You can decode this problem using character level LSTM.

In this you have to pass every character of the text in a LSTM cell.and at the last time step you will have a class which is the true label

You can use cross-entropy loss function.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-character-based-neural-language-model-keras/

This will give you complete idea